# Where to learn a computer language consisting of 0 and 1

Tags: binary, computer-science

I am learning the java programming language.I would like to know where to learn the computer language itself consisting of 0 and 1 Since I have not found any books on this topic.Tell me who knows

I tried looking for video tutorials or something like that but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is assembly language. However, this is different for every type of processor, hence people rarely use it anymore. You must be very good at it to beat a modern compiler.

And assembly is still not the raw byte code (the 0s and 1s). That translation is conceptually easy, but very time-consuming and even more error prone than assembly. Therefore nobody does that at least since 1980.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're learning Java, you might be referring to one of two things:

- [Java bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode)
- [Machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)

The Java compiler translates your source code into bytecode, stored in `.class` files. Bytecode is a type of processor-independent code (i.e. it is the same sequence of 0s and 1s irrespective of whether it's running on a computer based on an Intel processor, or an ARM processor, etc.). Bytecode is then translated (i.e. interpreted or compiled) into machine code by the [Java Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). The code consists of instructions which consist of a binary *opcode* (i.e. a sequence of 0s and 1s which tell the JVM what to do). However, because the numeric values of opcodes are hard to remember, each one has an associated descriptive *mnemonic*. The full instruction set is specified by the [JVM Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/).

Machine code is a different sequence of 0s and 1s for each type of processor (CPU). Each CPU type defines its own instruction set, consisting of opcodes which have associated descriptive mnemonics. When humans want to write machine code, they usually write in [Assembly Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), which is trivial to convert into machine code because the Assembler (i.e. a translator program) just has to translate each mnemonic into its binary opcode.